# Can't invoke generic initializer from protocol extension in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, initializer

I'm trying to call a `struct` I made from a protocol extension method I also made:

```
public struct AdjacentDifferenceArrayGenerator<T: Strideable where T.Stride == T>: GeneratorType {
    private var array: [T]
    public init<U: SequenceType where U.Generator.Element == T>(source: U) {
        self.array = source.adjacentDifference()
    }
    public mutating func next() -> [T]? {
        guard !array.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        defer {
            self.array = self.array.adjacentDifference()
        }
        return self.array
    }
}

public extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Strideable {
    public func adjacentDifference() -> [Self.Generator.Element.Stride] {
        var result: [Self.Generator.Element.Stride] = []
        var generator = AdjacentDifferenceGenerator(generator: self.generate())
        while let difference = generator.next() {
            result.append(difference)
        }
        return result
    }
}

public extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Strideable, Generator.Element.Stride: Strideable, Generator.Element.Stride.Stride == Generator.Element.Stride {
    public func pyramidOfAdjacentDifferences() -> [[Self.Generator.Element.Stride]] {
        var result: [[Self.Generator.Element.Stride]] = []
        var array = self.adjacentDifference()
        while !array.isEmpty {
            result.append(array)
            array = array.adjacentDifference()
        }
        //var generator = AdjacentDifferenceArrayGenerator(source: self)
        //while let differences = generator.next() {
            //result.append(differences)
        //}
        return result
    }
```

The four lines that are commented near the end, after the substitute algorithm, are trying to use the same algorithm as the method in the first extension.  When I uncomment out the first of those lines, the cursor waits at "`AdjacentDifferenceArrayGenerator`" and says: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AdjacentDifferenceArrayGenerator<_>' with an argument list of type '(source: Self)'"  That last "Self" is capitalized in the error message although it's uncapitalized in code.  Adding an explicit template bracket between the type and initializer arguments didn't help.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by taking out the first iteration:

```
public extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Strideable, Generator.Element.Stride: Strideable, Generator.Element.Stride.Stride == Generator.Element.Stride {
    public func pyramidOfAdjacentDifferences() -> [[Self.Generator.Element.Stride]] {
        var result = [self.adjacentDifference()]
        if result.first!.isEmpty {
            return []
        }

        var generator = AdjacentDifferenceArrayGenerator(source: result.first!)
        while let differences = generator.next() {
            result.append(differences)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

I have to test if that first iteration result is legitimate, since taking it out of the loop means I lost the automatic check.  I don't know if using "`self`" was the problem, or it was using a generic sequence instead of a definitive array was the problem.  Still need help here....

Comment: I had a "`typealias GType = AdjacentDifferenceArrayGenerator<Self.Generator.Element.Stride>`" and used that alias to construct `generator`, but that didn't help. But I now know that the element type could be computed just from the `source`'s type.